# Use Facebook C# SDK to Search for Places

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'd like to run a search on the Open Graph using the Facebook C# SDK

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=

But I'm not sure if I should use a Query or a POST or some form of FQL.

Update: From what I can tell I can build a query like this:

```
   var result = fb.Get(String.Empty,
                         new Dictionary<string, string>()
                              .SelectFields(new[] { "picture" })
                              .SelectIds(new[] { "123741737666932", "100001241534829" })
                              .SelectField("id"));
```

I can change the fb.Get to fb.Get("search"), but I'm not sure what to Select after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will get you exactly what you want:

```
Dictionary<string,object> searchParams = new Dictionary<string,object>();  
searchParams.Add("q", "coffee");     
searchParams.Add("center", "37.76,-122.427");     
searchParams.Add("type", "place");     
searchParams.Add("distance", "1000");

FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(token);
var searchedPlaces = fbClient.Get("/search", searchParams);
```

Comment: Haha you just barely beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("q", "coffee");
dict.Add("type", "place");
dict.Add("center", "-37.01,31.0015");
dict.Add("distance", "5");

var result = fb.Get("search", dict);
```